# svg image cant be opened in python

Tags: python, svg

My question is how to create an svg image and save as png in the same script. Currently, I have a python script that creates an svg image; then uses a system command to convert to png. The os.system function throws the following error from within the script:

```
** (inkscape:1828): WARNING **: Error:  Could not open file '/mnt/d/Desktop/best_openings/testImage.svg' with VFS
```

Here is a script that reproduces the same error:

```
from IPython.display import SVG
import os
mySVG = '<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><rect x="10" y="10" height="100" width="100" style="stroke:#ff0000; fill: #0000ff"/></svg>'
f1=open("testImage.svg", 'w+')
print >>f1,mySVG
f1.close
os.popen("inkscape -z -e testImage.png -w 1024 -h 1024 testImage.svg")
```

I have tried various different system calls that throw the same error:

```
ls | grep ".svg" | xargs -I file inkscape file -e file.png
inkscape image.svg --export-png=image.png
```

Comment: What happens when you add the full path in the `os.open` command (`os.popen("inkscape -z -e testImage.png -w 1024 -h 1024 /mnt/d/Desktop/best_openings/testImage.svg")`)? Some people were reporting similar issues and had it resolved by providing the full path. http://www.inkscapeforum.com/viewtopic.php?t=11652

Comment: good idea but I get the same error and I checked that the inscape command still works directly from the command line: just not from with the script as a system call

Comment: Did you try changing the file permissions?

Comment: Still the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [brackets after close to indicate it's a function call](https://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2008/06/04/gotcha-%E2%80%94-forgetting-parentheses/).

```
from IPython.display import SVG
import os
mySVG = '<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><rect x="10" y="10" height="100" width="100" style="stroke:#ff0000; fill: #0000ff"/></svg>'
f1=open("testImage.svg", 'w+')
print >>f1,mySVG
f1.close()
os.popen("inkscape -z -e testImage.png -w 1024 -h 1024 testImage.svg")
```

Answer (score 1):

Oddly enough the following code does not throw an error:

```
from IPython.display import SVG
import os
mySVG = '<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><rect x="10" y="10" height="100" width="100" style="stroke:#ff0000; fill: #0000ff"/></svg>'
f1=open("testImage.svg", 'w+')
print >>f1,mySVG
f1.close
f1=open("testImage2.svg", 'w+')
print >>f1,mySVG
f1.close
os.popen("inkscape -z -e testImage.png -w 1024 -h 1024 testImage.svg")
```

but there must be a better solution